# how to calculate the value of following question without overflow?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

### (nCr + nC(r+1) + nC(r+2) + .... + nCn)/2^n

---

value of this is atmost 1,but for large n(10^5) nCr value overflows.
can any1 give me an efficent approach to solve this(r<=n).
thanks.

Comment: $nCr = {n \choose r}$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135431/how-to-calculate-the-summation-sum-p-kn-binomnp-2n-quickly

Comment: To avoid overflow when working with ratios of factorials and powers you can make us of the Log Gamma Function which can be efficiently numerically calculated.